# Sitecore Custom profile

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

Using Sitecore 7.1, we have defined a custom profile with a custom user profile .Net object so that the user's values can be updated in the Security Manager.

In our site, we have a page to display the current user's profile.

If I update a user's details in the Security User Manager, I expect them to be updated on this page. This works fine locally but when we deploy to test (which has separate authoring and delivery servers), the updated details aren't displayed on the page. We have a custom database table that does contain the correct values so I don't know where the incorrect values are coming from (should I be looking at aspnet_Profile table?) ..

We are using `IAuthenticationManeger.GetActiveUser().Profile` to get the user to display.

Any ideas? Let me know if supplying any other code would help ...

Comment: Do your delivery instances have access to the same Core database as your authoring instance?

Answer (score 0):

If your are overriding the `Sitecore.Security.UserProfile` class and using `SetCustomProperty` method, then yes the values are saved in the aspnet_Profile database.  If you update a user profile in a dev environment, you would need to copy those changes to your test environment via serialization or package to see them there.

If you are doing something else, then you may want to post the code for your profile class so we can get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Yes, we are providing a wrapper for UserProfile that makes use of SetCustomProperty. On Test, Im creating a user their, updating in the User Manager, but then GetActiveUser().Profile isnt returning the updated values. If these values are stored in aspnet_Profile, then I dont know why they aren't being returned...